# Error comes while importing files by data.table

Tags: r

I'm new to R studio and was not well aware of this portal T&C, so was blocked for questing for 5 days.
I have a code for importing multiple files from any directory to R.
Using this code for doing so, but the problem is this code runs sometime and sometime it gets failed with mentioned error.
I tried to found the solution of this but yet not found any solution.

```
library(data.table)  
t = setwd("/home/dp/vishan/olp_data/19164/1/")
files <- file.info(list.files(path = t,pattern = "", full.names=TRUE))
files = rownames(files)[files$size > 0]
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
```

Error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'input' can not be a directory name, but must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you try to fread folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
files <- file.info(list.files(path = t,pattern = "", full.names=TRUE))
files <- subset(files, !isdir & size > 0)
temp <- lapply(rownames(files), fread, sep=',')
```

since `list.files` also shows directories. The data.frame you create in `files` can be easily subset on the `isdir` column which indicates if this is a directory or a file.

Comment: thanks but, its showing mentioned error.
Error in subset.default(files, !isdir) : object 'isdir' not found

Comment: Didn't realised you overwrite the `files`. sorry, now it should work.

Comment: temp <- lapply(rownames(subset(files, !files)), fread, sep=',')
error in this code "Error in !files : invalid argument type"

Comment: sorry sir, for bothering you again and again, actually i'm new to R so asking silly questions. Appolozise.

Comment: thanks al lot sir, got my answer! (didn't read your complete answer before asking). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sir, it works well but when I'm going to schedule it on cron, its gets failed with reason "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Expected sep (',') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 4 when detecting types from point 0:". Please help.